# Alternative a "portare il portatile"?

Tags: word-choice, single-words

La parola "portatile" è pressoché l'unica traduzione italiana di "laptop", "notebook", ecc.
Esistono delle alternative all'espressione "porto con me il portatile" che non risultino ripetitive del concetto (e del verbo) "portare"?

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE!

Comment: A volte uso "computerino", sulla falsariga di telefono -> telefoninol.

Comment: Grazie mille @Charo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dipende dal contesto della frase. Se il portatile è stato menzionato prima, non suona male dire in seguito qualcosa come “...domani lo porto con me”. Se no, si può riformulare per esempio con “avrò con me il portatile” e simili.

Comment: Mi pare di capire che in assenza di sinonimi (italiani) di "portatile" ma anche di alternative valide al verbo "portare" per esprimere tale concetto, l'unica soluzione sia una riformulazione dell'intera frase. Grazie

Comment: "Reco meco il portatile" ;)

Answer (score 2):

**Usare uno dei termini inglesi** laptop, notebook o (genericamente) computer. Mi sembra che siano ampiamente diffusi e compresi, e solo i puristi più ortodossi storcerebbero il naso.

Comment: Vero, però è scomodo avere traduzioni in italiano che risultino così simili ai verbi che più di frequente li accompagnano...